# Titanium Alloy - nested tabgroups

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Is it possible to have the `Tab` of one `TabGroup` contain another `TabGroup`?

Here's what I'm trying to do. This is the content of a `Tab` within the top `TabGroup`. I'm trying to add another `TabGroup` within it. It doesn't give any errors just doesn't display the second `TabGroup`...

```
<Alloy>
    <Tab title="Testing">
        <Window id="window" navBarHidden="true" title="Testing" class="container" >
            <TabGroup>
                <Tab title="Hello">
                    <Window title="Hello">
                        <Label>Hello</Label>
                    </Window>
                </Tab>
                <Tab title="Hello">
                    <Window title="Hello">
                        <Label>Hello</Label>
                    </Window>
                </Tab>
            </TabGroup>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

I'm trying to have a tab (positioned at the bottom) contain 2 tabs (positioned at the top). If there's a better way to do this please let me know!

Update:

Here's an example I found of what I'm trying to achieve. I don't actually think the inner tab group is an actual tab group?

[image: example]

Comment: Even if it worked, this is really bad idea.

Comment: Yeah on further though a tabgroup for the inner wouldn't work. I've updated my question with an image I found of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Are you talking about those blue buttons?

Comment: Yes those! Can't figure out what controls they are

Comment: It should be `TabbedBar` http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.TabbedBar

Answer (score 0):

`TabGroup` is the **most Parent** Element and `Tab`,`Window` are their child. So,I did't think,it is possible to add `TabGroup` to a `Tab`. But you can create your own `Tabgroup` then you can do what you want with it.